# AngularJs global service

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to store a response variable in a global service variable. This is my `service`:

```
(function() {
    angular.module('employeeApp')
        .service('constants',constants);

    function constants() {
        this.url = 'http://domain.dev/api/v1/';
            this.role =  '',
            this.companyid = '',
            this.name = ''
    }
})();
```

**loginFactory:**

```
factory.login = function(email,password)
        {
            var vm = this;
            vm.companyid = constants.companyid;

            data = {"email": email, "password": password};
            requestFactory.post(GLOBALS.url + 'login', data)
                .then(function (response) {
                    vm.role = response.data.result.Employee.Role;
                    vm.companyid = response.data.result.Employee.CompanyId;
                    factory.setToken(response.data.result.Employee.api_token);
                    $cookieStore.put('employeeid', response.data.result.Employee.EmployeeId);
                    $location.path('/home');

                }, function () {
                    console.log('Niet ingelogd!');
                });
        }
```

When I try to access companyid in my homecontroller it's empty. What am I doing wrong. Looking for hours right now but can't find a solution!

Comment: You don't have a return statement in your service. Could that be the problem?

Comment: @kubuntu I'm trying to set something in my factory.

Comment: Change commas in `constants()` to semicolons. Shoulld work

Comment: Nope still not working.

Comment: See working demo in answer below. If you're still having problems with it, they are likely from other parts of your application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the constants service into your loginFactory.
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

```
.factory('loginFactory', ['constants', function(constants) {
```

Also, you're not returning an object in your constants service

Comment: I've done that: `function authenticationFactory($cookieStore,$cookies,requestFactory,$location,GLOBALS,constants)
 {`

Answer (score 0):

Hey you need to inject the your service as a dependency to you factory

```
angular.module('employeeApp')
   .factory('loginFactory', ['constants', function(constants, $scope) {

$scope.login = function(email,password)
    {
        var vm = this;
        vm.companyid = constants.companyid;

        data = {"email": email, "password": password};
        requestFactory.post(GLOBALS.url + 'login', data)
            .then(function (response) {
                vm.role = response.data.result.Employee.Role;
                vm.companyid = response.data.result.Employee.CompanyId;
                factory.setToken(response.data.result.Employee.api_token);
                $cookieStore.put('employeeid', response.data.result.Employee.EmployeeId);
                $location.path('/home');

            }, function () {
                console.log('Niet ingelogd!');
            });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work unless there are problems in other parts of your app. Notice semi-colons instead of brackets in function `constant` and square brackets added to module declaration.

```
(function() {
    angular.module('employeeApp', [])
        .service('constants',constants);

    function constants() {
        this.url = 'http://domain.dev/api/v1/';
        this.role =  '';
        this.companyid = '';
        this.name = '';
    }
})();
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ranru/L9cfsb7L/)